# An Object Accesses its own Attributes in Another Method

Tags: perl, object, scope, attributes

Suppose I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

package Guy;
sub new {
        my $type = shift;
        my %params = @_;
        my $self = {};
        $self->{'First'} = $params{'First'};
        $self->{'Middle'} = $params{'Middle'};
        $self->{'Last'} = $params{'Last'};
        bless $self, $type;
}
sub printMe
{
        printf "-----------------------------------\n";
        printf "My type is: \"$self->{type}\"\n";        # Line 18
        printf "First  ::  $self->{First}\n";            # Line 19
        printf "Middle ::  $self->{Middle}\n";           # Line 20
        printf "Last   ::  $self->{Last}\n";             # Line 21
        printf "-----------------------------------\n";
}

package main;
my $dude = Guy->new( 'First' => "John", 'Middle' => "Jacob", 'Last' => "Smith" );
$dude->printMe();
```

Output is:

```
me@ubuntu1$ ./toy01.perl
Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $self"?) at ./toy01.perl line 18.
Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $self"?) at ./toy01.perl line 19.
Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $self"?) at ./toy01.perl line 20.
Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $self"?) at ./toy01.perl line 21.
Execution of ./toy01.perl aborted due to compilation errors.
me@ubuntu1$
```

So the problem here is that class method `printMe()` can't access attributes stored in the `$self` hash, which is populated in the constructor.  I'm so confused as to why.

In the constructor, `$self` is created as a hash, used to store the attributed passed into the constructor.  Is `$self` created with a local scope when it needs to be global, or something like that?  Or do I lack a command at the top of the `printMe()` method that makes `$self` visible, or something?

And how to refer to attribute `type`, which is an attribute that is set in the constructor but not stored in the `$self` hash?  (My `$self->{type}` call is obviously a desperate attempt to stumble upon the solution here.)
Any advice or feedback is appreciated here, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object is sent to the method as the first parameter, but you need to populate the variable yourself:

```perl
sub printMe
{
    my ($self) = @_;
    ...
```

Note that `$self->{type}` doesn't exist. Use `ref $self` or `blessed($self)` from [Scalar::Util](http://p3rl.org/Scalar::Util).

Also, using [printf](http://p3rl.org/printf) without a format string is useless. Use [print](http://p3rl.org/print) or [say](http://p3rl.org/say) instead, or use `printf` properly:

```perl
printf "First  ::  %s\n", $self->{First};
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got a good "how to fix this" answer which you've accepted. But it might be worth digging into what was going wrong in a bit more depth.

You have two subroutines (they're actually methods, but that's basically the same thing in Perl):

```
sub new {
  ...;
  my $self = {};

  # code populating $self
  ...;

  bless $self, $type;
}
```

And:

```
sub printMe {

  # code accessing $self

}
```

Inside `new()` you declare `$self` with [`my`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my). That's absolutely the right thing to do, but the effect of `my` is to create a "lexical" variable - that is one that is only visible inside the block of code where you declare it (that's inside the `new()` subroutine).

When you then try to access `$self` inside your `printMe()` subroutine, you get a warning - because that variable simply doesn't exist inside that subroutine. But obviously, you need access to that variable (or, at least, that value) inside `printMe()`. So how does that work?

Well, Perl comes with a lot of documentation. And the [perlobj](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj) manual page explains how the built-in object system works.

The section on [constructors](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj#Writing-Constructors) has an example of writing a `new()` method. It's pretty similar to yours. The crucial line of code is this one:

```
return $self;
```

This shows that the constructor method needs to return your blessed object. The equivalent line in your constructor is this:

```
bless $self, $type;
```

You're doing things in a slightly different way, but that's ok. It all works as expected. This is the last line of your method and a Perl subroutine will return the result of the last expression evaluation. So this is just the same as writing (the slightly more explicit):

```
return bless $self, $type;
```

Ok, so you have returned the object from your constructor and you're storing that object in your `$dude` variable:

```
my $dude = Guy->new(...);
```

Now we need to get that object back into the `printMe()` method so you can use it. The perlobj manual page has a section on [method invocation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj#Method-Invocation) that covers this:

> Calling a method on an object is written as `$object->method`.

And:

> When you call a method, the thing on the left side of the arrow is passed as the first argument to the method.

And if you read the section called [A Method is Simply a Subroutine](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj#A-Method-is-Simply-a-Subroutine), you'll see this:

> What makes a method special is that it expects to receive either an object or a class name as its first argument.

And there's an example method:

```
sub save {
    my $self = shift;

    open my $fh, '>', $self->path() or die $!;
    print {$fh} $self->data()       or die $!;
    close $fh                       or die $!;
}
```

And look! There's another `$self` variable. We're passing the object into the subroutine (implicitly, by using the `$object->method()` syntax) and we're storing the object in a new variable called `$self` which is also declared with `my` and, therefore, also only available inside the subroutine.

Looking back at your code, you're calling the method correctly:

```
$dude->printMe();
```

The only problem is that you're not setting up the `$self` variable inside your `printMe()` method. So to fix that, you just add this line to the start of your method:

```
my $self = shift;
```

Sorry... that went on rather longer than I expected. Hope it was useful.

Comment: This was awesome, thanks Dave!  I'm copying your feedback into my notebook...